# Submit an Alexa skill for approval without publishing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Does anyone know if Amazon allows you to submit a Skill for verification / testing but hold it from being published automatically (like Apple / Google allow for app submission)?

I've checked the Amazon developer docs and raised a support request with them - but so far no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from Amazon is that this feature is not yet available.